# How to make the BotAvatarImage value to be read such that the image is part of solution itself in BotFramework SDKV4 web channel?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, botframework, chatbot

I have created Chat BOT using Microsoft bot framework SDK V4 in C# and channel in Web Channel as part of which i created an index.html page using the tutorials and other posts. I am able to provide the BotAvatar image as url and that is working perfectly good but what i want is an image value to be assigned to this, where the image is part of solution itself.

Meaning in a given BOt project we have BOT folder,dialog folder and wwwroot folder and apart from this i have an image file in it.

I want this image file to read as an BOtAvatarimage when the index.html is opened after publishing it to Azure.

Current HTML i have

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Engineering Bot</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--
      For demonstration purposes, we are using the development branch of Web Chat at "/master/webchat.js".
      When you are using Web Chat for production, you should use the latest stable release at "/latest/webchat.js",
      or lock down on a specific version with the following format: "/4.1.0/webchat.js".
    -->
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat-es5.js"></script>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%
        }

        body {
            margin: 0
        }

        #webchat {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .navbar {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

            .navbar a {
                float: left;
                display: block;
                color: #f2f2f2;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 17px;
            }

                .navbar a:hover {
                    background: #ddd;
                    color: black;
                }

        .floating {
            padding: 16px;
            margin-top: 30px;
            height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main">
    </div>

    <script>
        const token = 'Token value';

        const styleOptions = {
            hideUploadButton: true,
            botAvatarImage: 'ImageUrl',
            botAvatarInitials: 'BF',
            userAvatarImage: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTXFpBTkKBW7JgYuePzhVoGkDDdZLVKQMZDbgy6j3C0sWvkkH1-',
            userAvatarInitials: 'WC',
            bubbleBackground: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, .1)',
            bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, .1)'
        };
        var d = new Date();
        var tzoffset = d.getTimezoneOffset();
        const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
            {},
            function (_ref) {
                const dispatch = _ref.dispatch;
                return function (next) {
                    return function (action) {
                        if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
                            dispatch({
                                type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                                payload: {
                                    name: 'webchat/join',
                                    value: tzoffset.toString()
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        return next(action);
                    };
                };
            });

        window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
            directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: token }),
            styleOptions: styleOptions,
            store: store,
            webSpeechPonyfillFactory: window.WebChat.createBrowserWebSpeechPonyfillFactory()
        }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
        document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now if we observe in above script, the BOT Avatar image we usually give an image url lets say a google image url is provided. If i give an google image url it works perfectly fine. Now, i want to give the image path which is part of solution/project itself.

I have tried the following:

botAvatarImage: '.\Logo.png'

Created an image folder and provided value as:

botAvatarImage: '.\Image\Logo.png'

None of these worked.

Is this right expectation, can we provide an image which is part of BOT solution or project itself? If yes how/in which format should the value be given as the once i gave does not work?

Comment: Not sure if this is still relevant but I think the reason that it doesn't work is because of the given url. You use a backslash: `.\Image\Logo.png` whereas you should use a forwards lash `/` in a url. Thus try `botAvatarImage: './Image/Logo.png',`

Comment: @Chiel  :  Yeah it worked thank Chiel,  Somehow, i missed the Forward slash point. Thanks Not sure how to upvote or accept a solution which was provided as part of comment but it worked. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: great! You could always upvote that comment…